# How do I reliably inject a meta tag onto a SharePoint page without editing the master page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I don't want to edit any master pages for obvious reasons given that I am on SharePoint Online.  But I am trying to achieve responsiveness on my sites.  For this, I would really like to use the viewport meta tag.

Something like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

How could I inject that? I've seen some javascript to inject a meta tag, but my fear is this would occur "too late" and even if it works in some of my tests... I may not know when it isn't working in production (or, I could write some more JS to check this, but I wouldn't want faulty code in production anyway).

Comment: god i am so glad i dont have to work with sharepoint anymore. this Q was from an old job I had years ago! SO just reminded me with a "Notable Question" achievement lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the built in Search Engine optimization settings (Settings > Site Collection Administration > Search Engine Optimization). These options allow for added SEO tags but can be "hijacked" for any metadata tag ;-)

More info [here](http://www.n8d.at/blog/how-to-add-viewport-meta-without-editing-the-master-page/)

Comment: Oh that's clever. Thank you. I also like the implications this have when doing remote provisioning. ...which is still an area of confusion for me so if you have a really great guide for this, please let me know! Lol

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working very well for me.  I was unaware some meta tags can still be appended after the head is parsed with the desired effect.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly

```
var metaTag=document.createElement('meta');
metaTag.name = "viewport"
metaTag.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(metaTag);
```